# how might I solve learnyounode http-collect without a third party library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node and I am working my way through the [nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io/) learnyounode interactive lessons and I am having an issue with the http-collect problem.

firstly the actual solution, which uses the third party package [Buffered List](http://npm.im/bl) to solve the problem, does not work when I run the `learnyounode verify` command. I'm not even sure how to test this out side of the learnyounode test. How would I do this? I'm guessing some sort of node service?

Secondly, as I don't really understand this I would really like to try implement it without a 3rd party package but I have no idea where to start. I'm not looking for a solution to be handed to me but would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction whether its a tutorial online or a particular method in the node documentation that may help.

For reference here is the learnyounode solution which fails for me

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (request) {
  request.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      return console.error(data)
    data = data.toString()
    console.log(data.length)
    console.log(data)
  }))  
})
```

The output from `learnyounode verify http-collect`

```
Verifying "HTTP COLLECT"...

ACTUAL:   ""
EXPECTED: "123"

ACTUAL:   null
EXPECTED: "Flat out like a swag no worries as dry as a big smoke. 
Lets throw a fruit loop how as stands out like not my
bowl of rice. "

ACTUAL:   null
EXPECTED: ""

# FAIL

Your solution to HTTP COLLECT didn't match the expected output.
Try again!
```

### Update: Possible Proxy Issue...

**Further Update: Not a proxy Issue, but leaving this Section here in case information is helpful to someone else**

So I believe I have figured out the Issue but have yet to figure out the solution. I think it is a proxy Issue as I am doing this on a work network. I arrived at this conclusion as I had the same error with the following

```
http.get({path:'http://www.google.com/index.html'}, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

once I changed the above snippit to the following, where our company proxy is  `http://http.proxy.somewhere.com:1234`, I no longer recieved the error for that snippit, unfortunitly this was not enough for the learnyounode verify.

```
http.get({ host: 'http.proxy.somewhere.com', path:'http://www.google.com/index.html', port: 1234}, function(res) {

  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

### Solution with Buffered List

The Issue was that the `bl` module was not installed locally, I had it installed globally originally and that seemed to cause an issue, not sure why, if anybody can explain why it might of been the Issue please do,

Comment: Yeah, I installed npm's 'bl' globally so I could use it again, and had the same problem. Thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to hear that. Weird, I actually just finished that exercise.
I checked your solution on my computer and it worked.
You installed bl prior to writing the program?    npm install bl

As far as a without a 3rd party package.

-If you use the response.on method - there are multiple data events so you will have to add them up in your callback and store them in a variable. 
-you will have to use response.setEncoding just like httpclient exercise; 
- use response.end method callback for the output

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution if you don't want to use 3rd party:

```
var http = require('http');
var info = [];

var url = process.argv[2];
http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        info.push(data);
    });
    res.on('error', console.error);
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(info.join('').length);
        console.log(info.join(''));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question without using a third party library:

The `response` object from `http.get` callback emits an *end* event. I use the same technique as the previous exercise to get `data` in string format then append it to a variable (starting as an empty string) on every *data* event, then log out result on the *end* event.

Below is my solution:

```
function httpGetCallback(response) {
  var result = '';

  function appendResult(data) {
    result += data;
  }

  function logResult() {
    console.log(result.length);
    console.log(result);
  }

  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', appendResult);
  response.on('end', logResult);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this by installing the [Buffered List](https://npmjs.org/package/bl) module locally. I had it originally install globally but for some reason that cause an issue. Still not sure why...