# Learnyounode http collect off by one

Tags: node.js

I'm learning node.js via the learnyounode tutorials and am stuck at the HTTP-COLLECT exercise. I want to get my code working without the help of a third party program. It's almost working, but for some reason it doesn't receive the first block of data from whatever source learnyounode is siphoning the data from, so my code is wrong. This is my code so far:

```
http = require("http");
var info = [];

http.get(process.argv[2],function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on("data",function(input){
        info.push(input);
    });
    res.on("error",console.error);
    res.on("end",function(){
        console.log(info.join(""));
    });
});
```

And the terminal output:

```
1.    ACTUAL:  "As busy as a fossicker mate built like a bluey. As dry as a sickie piece of piss mad as a beauty. As cunning as a trackies with get a dog up ya muster. Gutful of mate's rate piece of piss lets get some battler."
1.  EXPECTED:  "402"

2.    ACTUAL:  "We're going bottlo also come a holden. Grab us a bradman no dramas he hasn't got a ironman. She'll be right nipper no dramas she'll be right sheila. Mad as a pav also he hasn't got a barbie. "
2.  EXPECTED:  "As busy as a fossicker mate built like a bluey. As dry as a sickie piece of piss mad as a beauty. As cunning as a trackies with get a dog up ya muster. Gutful of mate's rate piece of piss lets get some battler."

3.    ACTUAL:  ""
3.  EXPECTED:  "We're going bottlo also come a holden. Grab us a bradman no dramas he hasn't got a ironman. She'll be right nipper no dramas she'll be right sheila. Mad as a pav also he hasn't got a barbie. "

4.    ACTUAL:  
4.  EXPECTED:  ""
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517267/how-might-i-solve-learnyounode-http-collect-without-a-third-party-library) post on SO but it didn't really help me since 1) I'm trying to use http.get() as specified in the hints of the exercise and 2) my problem doesn't seem to have to do with proxy issues. any hints/help would be appreciated, I'm not really sure how to fix the code from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'oh...After poking around a bit more, I found what was wrong: the first number was not data I was missing, it was just the length of the received text in characters. There was actually nothing wrong with the program itself. I fixed my code by adding `console.log(info.join("").length);` before the `console.log(info.join(""));` line.

Answer (score 2):

```js
res.on("end",function(){
        console.log(info.join(""));
    });
```

look no further, the mistake is right up there in this part, you didn't print the length of the string, as directed. There is no other issue with the code.
Here is my solution:

```js
var http = require('http');
var result = ''
var req = http.get(process.argv[2], (response)=>{
 response.setEncoding('utf8');
 response.on('data', (data)=>{
  result+=data.toString();
 });
 response.on('error', (e)=>{
 console.log(e);
 });
 response.on('end',()=>{
  console.log(result.length);
  console.log(result);
  result='';
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

because you did not print out the length of all characters before printing the string. Replace the statement in the 'end' event by:

```
datas = info.join("")
console.log(datas.length);
console.log(datas);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {

   response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {

     if (err)
       return console.error(err);
     data = data.toString();
     console.log(data.length);
     console.log(data);
   }));

 });
```